# zaptel error at installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, sip, phone-call

I am trying to install zaptel and libri in Ubuntu. As I've understood asterisk needs these files if I want to configure a conference call over sip.

I've downloaded zaptel and after make command I have the following errors:

```
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c: In function ‘pciradio_start_dma’:
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c:1701: error: implicit declaration of function ‘set_current_state’
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c:1701: error: ‘TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c:1701: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c:1701: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.c:1702: error: implicit declaration of function ‘schedule_timeout’
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel/pciradio.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1/kernel] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-31-generic'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/zaptel-1.4.12.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Need help. Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably better on serverfault (and I can't seem to comment on Andrea's answer) but you might be better off using [app_confbridge](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10) in Asterisk 10, if in your distribution. Then you will not need DAHDI (formerly Zaptel) installed at all to run a conference call.

Answer (score 0):

Zaptel is now called DAHDI [1]. Try installing it from the package manager (`apt-get install dahdi`).

Also, 1.4.12.1 is an old version, if you don't have a specific need for that version, just use what is present in your distribution.

[1] http://blogs.digium.com/2008/05/19/zaptel-project-being-renamed-to-dahdi/

Comment: thx for your response. Do you have any ideea about how to use it with asterisk? How to configure asterisk for conference calls?

Comment: I have not been using Asterisk for a long time; as far as I remember you have to use the MeetMe application. I suggest you first become familiar with Asterisk itself and then try to organize a conference call. A good resource for Asterisk is the www.voip-info.org wiki; I also see that there is a new official wiki for Asterisk: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Home. Finally, you will find some help in the asterisk-users ML: http://lists.digium.com/mailman/listinfo/asterisk-users. Hope that helps!